# Javascript Loop Iteration Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, for-loop

I want to run a for loop that will produce a new div (with class 'container') containing a single link. E.g. the first div will show 'link6.php', the second div will show 'link5.php' etc. However, currently it seems that the loop is running out the full loop in each div (I have attached a picture showing this).

```
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    $('#everything').append('<div class="container"></div>');
    var link = "link" + i + ".php" + "<br />";
    $('.container').append(link);
}
```

[image: Here is the image]

Thank you very much in advance. I am new at this and your help is much appreciated ;)

Comment: You should have had a insight look at jQuery documentation and understood their specification regarding DOM selection. However, I can help you with this.

Comment: Sorry, @EnglishMaster I am new to this! Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you append the div, you select all `.container` elements and append the text to each. There seems to be no reason why you couldn't do the following.

```
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    $('#everything').append('<div class="container">link'+i+'.php<br /></div>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used this and it worked really well. Much more simple than what I was getting at... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because everytime you do `$('.container').append(link);`, the `$('.container')` gathers all existing divs including the ones added in the previous iterations and appends your link to each.

Instead of re-gathering them, reuse the existing reference to the container. You can chain `append` and `appendTo`.

```js
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
  $('<div class="container"/>')  // create container
    .append("link" + i + ".php") // append container with link
    .appendTo('#everything');    // append container to everything
}
```

```css
#everything {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="everything"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my recommendation for your code. I recommend you to cache things first, and understand how jQuery's DOM selection works.

```
var everythingCached = $('#everything');
var container = $('<div class="container"></div>');

for (var i = 6; i >0; i--) {
    var cached = everythingCached.append(container);
    var link = "link" + i + ".php" + "<br />";
    cached.append(link);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47g4f14p/

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$(".container").append()`, it appends to **every** DIV with `class="container"`, not only the one you just appended in this loop.\

The simple way to fix this is to include `link` in what you append to `#everything`.

```
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    var link = "link" + i + ".php" + "<br />";
    $('#everything').append('<div class="container">' + link + '</div>');
}
```

Or you could create the container as an object:

```
$('#everything').append($('<div>', {
    "class": "container",
    html: "link" + i + ".php<br/>"
});
```

or you could assign the container to a variable and append to it:

```
var container = $('<div class="container">').appendTo("#everything");
var link = "link" + i + ".php" + "<br />";
container.append(link);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're giving each div the class of 'container' and then running the append() on all .containers.

You need to give the divs a unique ID, or refer to it directly by the object.
As an example:

```
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    $('#everything').append('<div class="container'+i+'"></div>');
    var link = "link" + i + ".php" + "<br />";
    $('.container'+i).append(link);
}
```

Comment: To be honest, this is fine, but I don't recommend it. There's no point of using classes in this case.